# foreach injection is not working in mybatis

Tags: sql, mybatis

Plz help me inject  tag into @Delete query.

```
@Delete({"<script>","${__sql}","</script>"})
public int Delete(String __sql, List<Map<String, Object>> list);
```

__sql :

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE KEY IN (<foreach collection='list' item='item' seperator=','> #{item.key} </foreach>)
```

I got error below:

```
Caused by: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'item' not found. Available parameters are [__sql, list, param1, param2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags in `${}` are not evaluated.
You need to use [SQL provider](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html) with `@Lang` instead.

```java
public interface YourMapper {
  @Lang(XMLLanguageDriver.class)
  @DeleteProvider(type = YourSqlProvider.class, method = "deleteSql")
  int Delete(String sql, List<Map<String, Object>> list);

  class YourSqlProvider {
    public String deleteSql(String sql) {
      return "<script>" + sql + "</script>";
    }
  }
}
```

This requires MyBatis 3.5.1 or newer, IIRC.

Comment: this solved the problem. thank you.