# Dynamic SQL request with MyBatis Velocity

Tags: java, mybatis

Here is an example that works:

```
public class Parameter {
  private final String name;
  private final Long Id;
  ... constructor and getters
}

@Mapper
public interface UserMyBatisRepository {
    @Select("select * from users WHERE users.name=@{name} #if($_parameter.id) AND users.id=@{id}#end")
    public List<User> find(Parameter p);
}
```

I want to add the field `sql` into the `Parameter` and to use the `Mapper` like this:

```
@Select("@{sql}")
public List<User> find(Parameter p);
or
@Select("$_parameter.sql")
public List<User> find(Parameter p);
```

It seems that it does not apply the formatting in such case because I keep getting the errors like:

```
### SQL: ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''select * from users WHERE users.name=@{name} #if($_parameter.id) AND u' at line 1

### SQL: select * from users WHERE users.name=@{name} #if($_parameter.id) AND users.id=@{id}#end
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{name} #if($_parameter.id) AND users.id=@{id}#end' at line 1
```

Is there any proper way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SQL Provider.

```java
// other imports...
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Lang;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.SelectProvider;
import org.mybatis.scripting.velocity.VelocityLanguageDriver;

@Mapper
public interface UserMyBatisRepository {

  @Lang(VelocityLanguageDriver.class)
  @SelectProvider(type = Provider.class, method = "find")
  List<User> find(Parameter p);

  class Provider {
    public String find(Parameter p) {
      return p.getSql();
    }
  }

}
```

`@Lang` is unnecessary if you specify `defaultScriptingLanguage` in the config.

p.s.
For the default XML scripting, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68221078/1261766).